# Bug? FSharp.GrpcCodeGenerator fails on timestamp of 1970-01-01

Tags: f#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a standard protobuf file on both client and server.

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

package Protocol.ProtoBuf;

service PatientService {
  // Get all patient names
  rpc GetAllPatients(GetAllPatientsRequest) returns (PatientListResponse);
}

message Patient {
    int32 PatientId =1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp BirthDate = 2;
    string FirstName =3;
    string LastName=4;
    google.protobuf.StringValue Mi=5;  // StringValue is the protobuf property type for Nullable<string>.
    int32 ChartNumber=6;
}

message GetAllPatientsRequest {}



message PatientListResponse {
    repeated Patient Patients = 1;
}
```

When GetAllPatients is tested on the server, it correctly returns the BirthDate as:

Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp Patient.BirthDate with a value of {"1970-01-01T00.00.00Z"}

However, in my client project when using FSharp.GrpcCodeGenerator to directly compile the proto file to F#, the returned value from the server shows the BirthDate field to have a ValueOption of ValueNone--that is I am not getting the BirthDate timestamp on the client side. (I am, however, getting all the other values).

How can I download the TimeStamp in F#? What am I missing?

Thanks for any help on this.

The client project is defined as:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\patient.proto" GrpcServices="Client" />
    </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc-FSharp.Net.Client" Version="0.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc-FSharp.Tools" Version="0.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Addendum: **Further testing shows that all birthdates are correctly downloaded except for 1970-01-01 which is being translated to a null value on the client. (The server does correctly send 1970-01-01).**

Comment: Your question is unclear. I assume the server isn't implemented in F# and you're unsure of the discrepancy. If [this](https://github.com/Arshia001/FSharp.GrpcCodeGenerator#what-else) is the code generator, there's a [note](https://github.com/Arshia001/FSharp.GrpcCodeGenerator#what-else) about the namespace for Google's well-known types that may explain the issue.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for your reply. The protobuf files are identical between the server and the client. The server is on a different machine and does not use F#. The client machine compiles into F# OptionValues. The client works well with the other types, but I can't seem to get the DateTime to come across. I understand the note (I think), but note   I'm not using namespace, but rather "package". Again, all works except for the timestamp. Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @DazWilkin Further study shows that the DateTime field for birthdate IS working--but fails for a birthdate of 1970-01-01. Why? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work correctly for 1970-01-01 (in f#) is:

```
let patientToDomain (x:Protocol.ProtoBuf.Patient) : Patient = {PatientId = match x.PatientId with
                                                                                | ValueNone  ->  failwith "Missing Patient Id"
                                                                                | ValueSome d -> d;
                                                                   BirthDate = match x.BirthDate with
                                                                                | ValueNone -> failwith "Missing BirthDate"
                                                                                | ValueSome d -> match d.ToDateTime() with
                                                                                                   | ValueNone -> DateTime(1970,01,01) 
                                                                                                   | ValueSome f -> f
                                                                   FirstName = match x.FirstName with  
                                                                                | ValueNone -> failwith "Missing FirstName"
                                                                                | ValueSome s -> s;
                                                                   LastName = match x.LastName with
                                                                                | ValueNone -> failwith "Missing LastName"
                                                                                | ValueSome s -> s;
                                                                   Mi =  match x.Mi with
                                                                          | ValueNone -> ""
                                                                          | ValueSome s -> if s.Value.IsNone 
                                                                                           then ""
                                                                                           else s.Value.ToString();
                                                                   ChartNumber = match x.ChartNumber with
                                                                                | ValueNone -> failwith "Missing ChartNumber"
                                                                                | ValueSome i -> i}
```

That is, substitute 1970-01-01 when null is detected. Any Better Ideas?