# How to send and receive 1970-01-01 by gRPC?

Tags: grpc

I'm (attempting) to use  gRPC protobuf files in a client/server network. One of the return types is:

```
global.Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp
```

which is encapsulating the value for birthdate.

One of the data values for birthdate is 1970-01-01 which the client is receiving as an empty/null field. (Client is using C#/F#).

How do I correctly send and receive 1970-01-01 using gRPC?

Comment: is the server also in C#? Could you share a little bit of code so I can help ?

Comment: @ClémentJean The server is written in C# with gRPC being the DTO from within an ASP.NET Core 3.1. The client is written using FSharp.gRPCCodeGenerator.  I'm happy to share any code you'd like, what would you like to see? I have written a few integration tests on the server. The server does correctly transmit the 1970-01-01 date, but for some reason the client does not return this date to the client app. For this date, 1970-01-01, and apparently only for this date, a null value is returned. I don't know why (or where to look). Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @ClémentJean More information is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71501055/bug-fsharp-grpccodegenerator-is-not-downloading-protobuf-timestamps